# How to properly type define event.target.value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-conversion, event-handling, typescript-typings

I'm authoring a node package but I'm having bit of an issue with my [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) definitions. To be more specific **I find the definition of `event.target.value` super confusing**

#### Issue description:

I have the following event handler:

```js
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react' 

type FieldEvent = ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>

export const useField = <T>(input: T) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(input)

  const handleChange = (event: FieldEvent) => {
    const { name, value: eventValue } = event.target
    // @ts-expect-error
    setValue(eventValue)
  }

  return [input, handleChange]
}
```

The expression `setValue(eventValue)` results in the following error:

> Argument of type '`string`' is not assignable to parameter of type '`SetStateAction<T>`'.

I was a bit surprised by this, given a lot of exported components use different `event.target.value`. Eg date-picker return `Date` type, select `Object`, etc.

#### Issue investigation

Naturally I went to check the imported `ChangeEvent` react exports to see if it has correct definitions, but this appears to be correct

```
interface ChangeEvent<T = Element> extends SyntheticEvent<T> {
    target: EventTarget & T;
}
```

so according to this definition it should inherit the type of the `Element` that was passed to the `SyntheticEvent`

so I followed the chain to the `HTMLInputElement` declaration located in `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts` which is where the crux of the issue lies

```js
interface HTMLInputElement extends HTMLElement {
  value: string
  //... rest
}
```

I checked back and it appears all the native `<input>` elements default to `string` as their value type, which I guess make sense.

#### Solving the issue

Obviously this is not ideal, given this does not represent the `event.target.value` behavior in a lot of the [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) projects that use third-party-packages *(which my package is supposed to support)*. Consider the following codesandbox

[image: Edit Passed event value]

The returned `event.target.value` is as you'd expect of `typeof number`

[image]

that leads me to the question, should I simply override the `ChangeEvent` with the following definition?

```
ChangeEvent<{ value: T, name: string } & HTMLInputElement>
```

or would this be considered a bad practice? Or is there some better way to go about doing this altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'm not 100% sure if this is the correct approach but it seems to work fine for my use-case, albeit the typing seems a tiny bit odd, but basically I'm overwriting the passed type argument to `ChangeEvent` and extending it by a union of one the HTML elements.

```
export type FieldEvent<T> = ChangeEvent<
 { value: T, name?: string } &
 (HTMLInputElement | HtmlTextAreaElement | HTMLSelectElement)
>
```

This overwrites the type definition of the ChangeEvent, then you just need to create a handler function that extends the type argument

```
export type FieldHanderFunction<T> = (event: FieldEvent<T>) => void
```

so then inside my hook, it basically comes down to:

```
const useField<T> = (input: T) => {
 const handleChange = (event: FieldEvent<T>) => {
  // ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`handleChange` is not match to required params.

I've tried and it worked:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(1);
  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<{
    name?: string | undefined,
    value: unknown | number
  }>, child: React.ReactNode) => {
    setSelected(e.target.value as number);
  };

  return (
    <Select value={selected} onChange={handleChange}>
      <MenuItem value={1}>One</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={2}>Two</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={3}>Three</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  );
}
```